# Convert Ienumerable<int> to array and add to list C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a simple code:

```
            List<int[]> list = new List<int[]>();

            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {

                var vec = vector.Skip(index).Take(width);
                var v = vec.ToArray();
                list.Add(v);
                index = index + width;

            }
            string toDisplay = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list);
            MessageBox.Show(toDisplay);
```

This is vector:

```
int[] vector = new int[length];

        Random z = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            vector[i] = z.Next(-100, 100);
        }
```

What I want to do is to slice my vector on smaller vectors and add them to list of int. Using my code I only get `System.Int32[]` in MessageBox. I know that maybe my code it's not the right way. I barely know C#. 
How can I do this in other way?

Comment: Can you also share your **vector** details?

Comment: I've  edited my question

Comment: You haven't posted enough information to reproduce the problem. Most of this code can be removed though. Use [List.AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.7.2) to add the IEnumerable, ie `list.AddRange(vector.Skip(index).Take(width));`

Comment: @bezet where do `x` and `index` come from? Post something that compiles.

Comment: Before the loop: int index = 0;

Comment: `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list)` outputs all `int[]` and separates them with new-line. But  `int[].ToString` uses `Object.ToString` which just returns the type-name(in this case `System.Int32[]`). If you wanted to separate each `int` with comma you could use: `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.Select(arr => string.Join(",", arr)))`

Comment: `List<int[]> list` is a list of *arrays*, not numbers. Calling `ToString()` on an array returns the array's type. If you want a list of numbers change the list type to `List<int>`

Comment: What do you want to do? Display all numbers? Or all numbers in a page?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you mean to slice the initial array into smaller chunks and display them in a single line. This can be done using Linq as follows.

```
var StringToDisplay
    = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.Select(iList => String.Join(",", iList)));
```

Answer (score 0):

`List<int[]> list` is a list of arrays, not numbers. Calling `ToString()` on an array uses `Object.ToString()` which returns the object's (array's) type.

If you want to display a list of *pages*, you should change your string construction code to work with the inner arrays. One option is to use LINQ :

```
var lines=from page in list
          select string.Join(",", page);
string toDisplay = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```

It's better to use StringBuilder though, to avoid generating a lot of temporary strings:

```
var builder=new StringBuilder();
foreach(var page in list)
{
    builder.AppendLine(string.Join(",", page));
}
string toDisplay = builder.ToString();
```

If you want a list of numbers change the list type to List. You can also simplify the code by using AddRange, eg  :

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    var vec = vector.Skip(index).Take(width);
    list.AddRange(vec);
    index = index + width;
}

string toDisplay = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines);
```